# Не могу установить несколько редакторов nicEdit на страницу

Tags: javascript, html, веб-программирование

Я хочу установить несколько редакторов nicEdit с разными кнопками на свой сайт, но если я пытаюсь это сделать, то устанавливается только тот, который я задал первым, несмотря на то, что я сделал все в точности, как было в демо: http://nicedit.com/demos.php?demo=2

Вот код:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    bkLib.onDomLoaded(
        function() {
            new nicEditor({
                    buttonList: ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'strikethrough', 'left', 'center', 'right', 'justify', 'ol', 'ul', 'nicedit_wiris_editor', 'removeformat']
                }
            ).panelInstance("body_id");
            new nicEditor({
                buttonList: ['nicedit_wiris_editor', 'removeformat']
            }).panelInstance("question_title_id");

        }
    );

</script>
```

Comment: скорее всего в panelInstance указан не правильный id

Comment: @ИльяЗеленько нет, id указан правильный. Если добавлять по одному, то все работает. Проблемы возникают, когда пытаюсь добавить сразу несколько

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была решена путем дополнительной проверки на существование тегов:

```js
bkLib.onDomLoaded(function() {
            if ($('#body_id').length)
                new nicEditor({
                    buttonList: ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'strikethrough', 'left', 'center', 'right', 'justify', 'ol', 'ul', 'nicedit_wiris_editor', 'removeformat']
                }).panelInstance('body_id');
            if ($('#question_title_id').length)
                new nicEditor({
                    buttonList: ['nicedit_wiris_editor', 'removeformat']
                }).panelInstance('question_title_id');
            if ($('#answer_title_id').length)
                new nicEditor({
                    buttonList: ['nicedit_wiris_editor', 'removeformat']
                }).panelInstance('answer_title_id');
        });
```